# Trying to use "==" operator on a random string from a List

Tags: c#, windows, list

So i've wanted to create a small program out of boredom and got stuck on CS0019 error can't really find a way to fix it so i hope you guys can help me.

```
 string[] words = {"moment","100%","French",
            "I am Dumb","god","satan","keyboard","Error #789","mouse","anime","programming",
            "Technoblade","phone","autrorization","kolechia","arstozcka","LaBrava","water","uP",
            "folklore","computer","science","analog","origami","arithmetics","stupid","english"}; 
                                                                                                
            Random random = new Random();
            string index = random.Next(words.Length);
            Console.WriteLine(words[index]);
            int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            
            if(input == words[index]){
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Correct");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Correct++;
            }
```

Comment: Please include the actual error message. Very few people will recognize CS0019 for what it is and will have to look it up. Don't make them do that.

Comment: Also, add the line which is giving the exception

Comment: It looks like you are comparing an `int` to a `string` - you can't do that.

Comment: `string index = random.Next(words.Length);` this will return an `int`, should be `int index = random.Next(words.Length);`

Comment: You either want `input == index`  or `string input = Console.ReadLine();`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but I assume you are trying to find corresponding index of a random word, so this fix would do it:

```
int index = random.Next(words.Length); // int instead of string

if(input == index) // index instead of words[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// TRY THİS

        int Correct = 0;
        string[] words = {"moment","100%","French",
        "I am Dumb","god","satan","keyboard","Error #789","mouse","anime","programming",
        "Technoblade","phone","autrorization","kolechia","arstozcka","LaBrava","water","uP",
        "folklore","computer","science","analog","origami","arithmetics","stupid","english"};

        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.Next(words.Length);
        Console.Write("Random word: ");
        Console.WriteLine(words[index]);
        Console.Write("İnput number: ");
        int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (words[input] == words[index])
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Correct");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Correct++;
        }else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("False");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Whenever you propose a solution please provide explanation as well, not just code.